# How to use minus/set complement operator correctly in R?

Tags: r, operator-overloading

I wanted to create a new data frame, `df2`, by subsetting an existing data frame, call it `df`, by the rows for which the values of one of its columns, call it `column`, are non-zero.

What I tried at first was:

```
df2 <- df[-(df$column == 0), ]
```

However, this did not work. What did work was:

```
df2 <- df[(df$column != 0), ]
```

I get why the second one worked, but I don't understand why the first one didn't work, except for [operator overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading).

Specifically, running `-(df$column == 0)` and `(df$column !=0)` return different results -- the former isn't even a logical vector, but -1 times the logical vector `(df$column == 0)`. So everywhere I wanted the value 1, it had the value 0, and everywhere I wanted it to have the value 0, it had the value -1. Now I know it would not have been that difficult to fix, say by writing
 `1 -(df$column == 0)`, but the point is that I did not expect the operator `-` to behave that way, I expected it to behave as the set complement operator. (I.e. I did not even anticipate that there would have been a problem, so I was not thinking about how to fix the problem.)

**Concrete Question:** How does the R language decide whether and when to interpret the `-` operator as: (1) set complement operator (2) subtraction operator (3) multiplication by -1 ?

All of the documentation I found only addresses the use of the operator `-` as (2) subtraction operator, but doesn't mention how R disambiguates between (1) and (3).

Also, I know that (2) and (3) are more or less mathematically equivalent, but that might not mean that their implementations are the same. (E.g. matrix inversion in MATLAB.)

Comment: The minus in indexing works for numerical indices, not for logical indices. Not because the `-` operator is special, but because `[` treats negative indices as a negative selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the complication arises because you're using the values 0 and 1, which are also the numerical equivalents of `True` and `False`. So I will try to explain what went wrong with your code above by using a case that `df` has only two rows, and different numbers:

```
df<- data.frame(column = matrix(c(2,3), nrow=2))
> df
  column
1      2
2      3
```

Calling `(df$column==3)` returns two logical values:

```
> df1$column==3
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Because `TRUE=1` and `FALSE=0`, when you call `df[-(df$column == 3), ]` is the same as calling `df[-(c(0,1),]`, because in both cases you are removing the 1st row (no 0-indexing in R).

```
> df1[-(df1$column==3),]
[1] 3
> df1[-c(0,1),]
[1] 3
```

The reverse is true when you call `df[(df$column != 3),]`, because this time you are retaining the 1st row.

```
> df[(df$column != 3),]
[1] 2
> df[c(1,0), ]
[1] 2
```

What you were trying to do is remove the row for which `df$column==3`, but in order to that you need to know what row number it is, so you need its index. That's when you call the `which` function. So you would do:

```
df2 <- df[-which(df1$column == 3),]
```

Other than that, your understanding of how `-` is used in `R` is correct, and I think `R` decides how to use it, based on the context.

**Disclaimer**
I am sorry for the long, and maybe pedantic answer, I just did want to assume anything.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you -- I did not know that R did not do 0-indexing or negative indexing.

Answer (score 2):

The `-` operator is implemented as a function that takes one or two arguments.

```
> `-`
function (e1, e2)  .Primitive("-")
```

So the expression `-a` is interpreted to mean `-(a)` and `a - b` is interpreted as `-(a, b)`.

With one argument `-` returns the additive inverse (ie. it reverses the sign of the argument), and with two arguments it does subtraction.

```
> `-`(3)
[1] -3
> `-`(3, 1)
[1] 2
```

It doesn't do set operations.